# WordPress function not formatting code properly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type in WordPress and I'm using a loop in a function so that I can call the listings using a shortcode.

I am adding to a string using `.=` as I have read around that this is the best way to do it.

The problem is that it isn't formatting the code in the correct format, please see code below.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'gms_product', 'posts_per_page' => 30 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

function get_the_products() {
    global $loop;
    $code = '';
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $code .=    '<a href="#"><h3>'.the_title().'</h3></a>';
    endwhile;
    return $code;
}
```

The output looks like this.

```
post1post2 <a href="#"><h3></h3></a><a href="#"><h3></h3></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [get_the_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)

```
$code .=    '<a href="#"><h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3></a>';
```

Comment: Indeed, the difference between `the_title()` and `get_the_title()` is that the latter is used to get the title of a post `outside of the loop`

Comment: As a side note, although it's not a common practice, you can pass `false` as the third parameter of `the_title` so that it does not echo the title. Here, I'd use `get_the_title` too though.